# Visual C++ inliner assembler and defining a string?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

How can I get VC inliner assembler to accept something like:

```
__asm
{
  call L1
  db "Hello",0
  L1:
  nop
  nop
}
```

Or I have to use `_emit 0xxNNh` all the way?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? The data can be put before the `__asm` as a regular C string `char Hello[] = "Hello";`.

Comment: It is not the same thing Bo. I need the data to be embedded and contained within the asm block. Think of shellcode for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use data directives in inline assembly.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70hd396.aspx for explanation.